# Search functionality with pagination

Tags: php, sql, pdo, pagination

Good day,

Could someone please assist /advise as I am trying to implement pagination along with a search / filter functionality?

The search functionality works without the pagination and the pagination works without doing a filter / search, but I am receiving the below error when trying to do a category search with implementing pagination:

Error:

```
Uncaught exception: 'PDOException'

Message: 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND category = 'for Sale'' at line 14'
```

Pagination without search / filtering (working):

```
public static function paginate($page)
    {
        $db = static::getDB();

        // get the total number of records
        $total_records = (int) $db->query('SELECT COUNT(id) FROM posts')->fetchColumn();

        // get the total number of pages
        $perpage = 2;
        $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $perpage);

        // Get the specified page of records
        $start = $perpage * ($page - 1);
        $sql = ' SELECT *, posts.id as postId,
            users.id as userId,
            posts.created_at as postCreated,
            users.created_at as userCreated
            FROM posts
            INNER JOIN users
            ON posts.user_id = users.id
            ORDER BY posts.created_at DESC
            LIMIT :limit
            OFFSET :offset';

        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':limit', $perpage, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':offset', $start, PDO::PARAM_INT);

        $stmt->execute();

        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        return [$result, $page, $total_pages];
    }
```

Search / filtering without pagination (working):

```
public static function search($location, $category, $type, $bedrooms, $bathrooms, $minamount, $maxamount)
    {
        $db = static::getDB();

    
        $sql = 'SELECT *,

        posts.id as postId,
        users.id as userId,
        posts.created_at as postCreated,
        users.created_at as userCreated
        FROM posts
        INNER JOIN users
        ON posts.user_id = users.id
        
        WHERE location = :location';


        if ($category != '') {
            $sql .= ' AND category = :category';
        }

        if ($type != '') {
            $sql .= ' AND type = :type';
        }

        if ($bedrooms != '') {
            $sql .= ' AND bedrooms = :bedrooms';
        }

        if ($bathrooms != '') {
            $sql .= ' AND bathrooms = :bathrooms';
        }

        if ($minamount != '') {
            $sql .= ' AND amount >= :minamount';
        }

        if ($maxamount != '') {
            $sql .= ' AND amount <= :maxamount';
        }


        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue(':location', $location, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        if ($category != '') {
            $stmt->bindValue(':category', $category, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }

        if ($type != '') {
            $stmt->bindValue(':type', $type, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }

        if ($bedrooms != '') {
            $stmt->bindValue(':bedrooms', $bedrooms, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        }

        if ($bathrooms != '') {
            $stmt->bindValue(':bathrooms', $bathrooms, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        }

        if ($minamount != '') {
            $stmt->bindValue(':minamount', $minamount, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        }

        if ($maxamount != '') {
            $stmt->bindValue(':maxamount', $maxamount, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }

        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $result;
    }
```

Search with pagination (not working correctly):

```
    public static function paginatesearch($page, $location, $category, $type, $bedrooms, $bathrooms, $minamount, $maxamount)
    {
        $db = static::getDB();

        // get the total number of records
        $total_records = (int) $db->query('SELECT COUNT(id) FROM posts')->fetchColumn();

        // get the total number of pages
        $perpage = 2;
        $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $perpage);

        // Get the specified page of records
        $start = $perpage * ($page - 1);

        $sql = 'SELECT *,

        posts.id as postId,
        users.id as userId,
        posts.created_at as postCreated,
        users.created_at as userCreated
        FROM posts
        INNER JOIN users
        ON posts.user_id = users.id
      
        WHERE location = :location
        LIMIT :limit
        OFFSET :offset
        ';


        if ($category != '') {
            $sql .= ' AND category = :category';
        }

        if ($type != '') {
            $sql .= ' AND type = :type';
        }

        if ($bedrooms != '') {
            $sql .= ' AND bedrooms = :bedrooms';
        }

        if ($bathrooms != '') {
            $sql .= ' AND bathrooms = :bathrooms';
        }

        if ($minamount != '') {
            $sql .= ' AND amount >= :minamount';
        }

        if ($maxamount != '') {
            $sql .= ' AND amount <= :maxamount';
        }


        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':limit', $perpage, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':offset', $start, PDO::PARAM_INT);

        $stmt->bindValue(':location', $location, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        if ($category != '') {
            $stmt->bindValue(':category', $category, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }

        if ($type != '') {
            $stmt->bindValue(':type', $type, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }

        if ($bedrooms != '') {
            $stmt->bindValue(':bedrooms', $bedrooms, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        }

        if ($bathrooms != '') {
            $stmt->bindValue(':bathrooms', $bathrooms, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        }

        if ($minamount != '') {
            $stmt->bindValue(':minamount', $minamount, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        }

        if ($maxamount != '') {
            $stmt->bindValue(':maxamount', $maxamount, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }

        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return [$result, $page, $total_pages];
    }
```

Method in the controller for the search with pagination:

```
    public function searchAction()
    {
        $page = $_GET['page'] ?? 1; 

        list($posts, $page, $total_pages) = Post::paginatesearch($page, $_POST['location'], $_POST['category'],$_POST['type'],$_POST['bedrooms'],$_POST['bathrooms'],$_POST['minamount'],$_POST['maxamount']);    
       
        $images = Image::getAll();

        View::renderTemplate('Home/index.html', [
            'posts' => $posts,
            'images' => $images,         
            'currentPage' => $page,
            'nbPages' => $total_pages,         
        ]);
    }
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Add `LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset` at the _end_ of your query. They go _after_ `WHERE` and `AND`

Comment: @brombeer I have added  `$sql .= "\nLIMIT :limit";
        $sql .= "\nOFFSET :offset";` at the end of the query and the search form are now working - thank you very much! I will accept it as the solution ( should you perhaps want to post it as an answer).